# "jquery_file_upload.id is part of the primary key but is not specified to be 'not null'"

Tags: database

I have installed the [jQuery File Upload](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_file_upload) module, and I get the following error:

> jquery_file_upload.id is part of the primary key but is not specified to be 'not null'

What does that error message mean, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Are you asking for a module that has been developed from others, and which is hosted on Drupal.org?

Comment: Yes sorry. It is on my drupal  7.16 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is about the schema currently used by the module, which defines the primary key using [the following code](http://drupalcode.org/project/jquery_file_upload.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/jquery_file_upload.install).

```
function jquery_file_upload_schema() {
  $schema['jquery_file_upload'] = array(
      'description' => t('Stores files sizes for each user.'),
      'fields' => array(
          'id' => array(
              'description' => t('auto increment'),
              'type' => 'serial',
              'size' => 'normal',
          ),
          'uid' => array(
              'description' => t('registered user'),
              'type' => 'int',
              'unsigned' => TRUE,
              'not null' => TRUE,
              'default' => 0,
          ),
          'file_name' => array(
              'description' => t('File Name.'),
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'length' => '255',
              'not null' => TRUE,
          ),
          'file_size' => array(
              'description' => t('File Size.'),
              'type' => 'float',
              'size' => 'big',
              'default' => 0,
          ),
      ),
      'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

The correct definition would be the following one, as the fields that are part of the primary key should be declarated as "NOT NULL."

```
function jquery_file_upload_schema() {
  $schema['jquery_file_upload'] = array(
      'description' => t('Stores files sizes for each user.'),
      'fields' => array(
          'id' => array(
              'description' => t('auto increment'),
              'type' => 'serial',
              'size' => 'normal',
              'not null' => TRUE,
          ),
          'uid' => array(
              'description' => t('registered user'),
              'type' => 'int',
              'unsigned' => TRUE,
              'not null' => TRUE,
              'default' => 0,
          ),
          'file_name' => array(
              'description' => t('File Name.'),
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'length' => '255',
              'not null' => TRUE,
          ),
          'file_size' => array(
              'description' => t('File Size.'),
              'type' => 'float',
              'size' => 'big',
              'default' => 0,
          ),
      ),
      'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

There is nothing you can do, if not opening an issue report for the module, in [its issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/jquery_file_upload?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All). Be sure there isn't already a report about that.

Comment: can I not just edit it?

Comment: Editing the code of a module hosted on Drupal.org is not a good idea, just for the fact you should edit the code every time you update the module.

Comment: it is not hosted on drupal it's just a drupal installation.

Comment: jquery_file_upload.module is hosted on Drupal.org; it's not a custom module you developed.

Comment: how can i fix it then?

Comment: Submit an issue report for the module, on Drupal.org. There isn't anything else that you can do.